# Toggle fusion table layers: How to clear all other checkboxes when new box checked

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

EDIT: Fixed with radio buttons, here's the js toggle function to hide all layers before loading this layer:

```
function toggleLayer(this_layer){
    layer_0.setMap(null);
    layer_1.setMap(null);
    layer_2.setMap(null);
    this_layer.setMap(map);

}
```

I am toggling fusion table layers on the same map with JavaScript, which is working fine for me. However, for my purposes two layers must not display at the same time (each fusion table layer contains colored shape files on a gradient, creating a mess when they display overtop one another).

This is the code I'm using to toggle the fusion table layers:

```
function toggleLayer(this_layer){
  if(this_layer.getMap()) {
   this_layer.setMap(null)
  } else {
   this_layer.setMap(map);
  }
}

//And here's the HTML 

<form name="checkbox">
  <input class="menu" type="checkbox" id="show_hide_layer_0" checked onchange="toggleLayer(layer_0); "/>
  <label>layer_0</label>
  <input class="menu" type="checkbox" id="show_hide_layer_1" checked onchange="toggleLayer(layer_1)"/>
  <label>layer_1</label>
   <input class="menu" type="checkbox" id="show_hide_layer_2" checked onchange="toggleLayer(layer_2)"/>
  <label>layer_2</label>
</form>
```

I need to ensure only one fusion table layer is visible at a time. Right now this code allows all three boxes to be checked, which makes all three fusion table layers visible, creating a mess on the map.

Is there a way to uncheck all the other boxes when a new box is checked? Help is much appreciated. Should I be using radio buttons instead?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Fixed with radio buttons, here's the js toggle function to hide all layers before loading this layer:

```
function toggleLayer(this_layer){
layer_0.setMap(null);
layer_1.setMap(null);
layer_2.setMap(null);
this_layer.setMap(map);

}
```